# How many Rabbit Hutches can take on a Spider Den?

Tags: dont-starve

I'm building a bunch of Rabbit Hutches circling a Spider Den to create a silk farm. I also realized that this could also a bunny puff farm so I would like the balance between bunnymen and spiders to be as close to even as possible in order that some bunnymen die and some spiders die.

Does anyone know how many rabbit hutches can take on a level 3 spider den?

Comment: This question sounds completely insane for a grown man to be asking.

Comment: [On the wiki](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Spider#Spider) it's written that 4 hutches should suffice, but there's no reference to the tier level of the den.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my answer will help you but every Spider Den contains a finite number of spiders, so, the farm won't last really much :

> Tier 1: 3 Spiders 
>   Tier 2: 6 Spiders(1 will be a Warrior) 
>   Tier 3: 9 Spiders(3 will be Warriors)

Source: [Don't Starve Wiki / Spider Den](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Spider_Den)

Sorry if I missunderstood your question and Good Luck playing!

EDIT 1: I made some calculations and about **3-4 Hutches** should be enough to finish a **Tier 3 Spider Den**, maybe even 2. I calculated all this by scaling the health and damage of a bunnyman with the health and damage of a spider and then multiplied it with the max number of spiders that can be spawned and added bunnymen to this. I think I just got it right, good luck with all that and all I can recommend is experiment it in-game.

EDIT 2: If your sanity is low, I can guarantee 2 Hutches are enough, because of the damage multiplier of the bunnyman, so 1 bunnyman can finish a spider in 2 hits and a spider can finish a bunnyman in 10 hits. (only if your sanity is low and the dmg of bunnymen is 60!)